# OptaPlanner, excluded solution shows up

Tags: optaplanner

Please help me to understand DRL with this simple task assignment project. 2 workers id=1 and 2, 3 tasks id=1,2,3, each task has a duration in second. The duration for task 1 and 3 is a little bit more than task 2. At beginning I use following rule (only one rule) trying to balance total time for each worker, So I expect one worker takes task 1 and 3 while the other takes task 2.

```
rule "fairness"
    when
        $worker: Worker()
        accumulate(
            Task(worker == $worker, $d: durationInSec);
            $s: sum($d*$d)
        )       
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$s.longValue());
end
```

the result is all tasks are ALWAYS assigned to worker 1. I wanted to debug the issue and replaced the rule above with following 2 rules:

```
rule "A" 
    when
        $worker: Worker(id == 1) // for worker 1
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1); // hard score -1
end

rule "B"
    when
        $worker: Worker(id == 2) // for worker 2
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1); // soft score +1
end
```

I thought worker 1 would be excluded because of rule "A", but the result was still, worker 1 got all 3 tasks, with this output:

```
o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase : Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (30001), best score (-3hard/3soft), score calculation speed (7309/sec), step total (12948).
o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver: Solving ended: time spent (30002), best score (-3hard/3soft), score calculation speed (7258/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (NON_REPRODUCIBLE)
```

I expect worker 2 takes all 3 tasks with score 0hard/3soft. Following is part of my Solution class, where is the problem?

```
@PlanningSolution
@Entity
public class Solution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private SolverStatus solverStatus;
    
    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftLongScore score;
    
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @OneToMany
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "workerRange")
    private List<Worker> workerList;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    @OneToMany
    private List<Task> taskList;
    ...
    
    
@Entity
@PlanningEntity
public class Task implements Comparable<Task> {
    
    @PlanningId
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "workerRange")
    private Worker worker;
```

When putting a println in RHS I do see both worker 1 and 2 are printed out:

```
System.out.println("worker=" + $worker.toString() + ", task=" + $tb.toString() + "; " +
    scoreHolder.getHardScore() + "hard/" + scoreHolder.getHardScore() + "soft");

...
worker=1, task=2; -3hard/-3soft
worker=1, task=1; -3hard/-3soft
worker=2, task=3; -3hard/-3soft
worker=2, task=2; -3hard/-3soft
worker=2, task=1; -3hard/-3soft
worker=1, task=3; -3hard/-3soft
worker=2, task=1; -3hard/-3soft
worker=2, task=1; -3hard/-3soft
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules "A" and "B" penalize/reward purely for the existence of these two workers, they don't say anything about any tasks assigned to them.

At the first glance, I don't see anything wrong with the first constraint ("fairness"). You can always add `System.out.println(...)` in the `then` section of the rule to debug it.

Alternatively, if you prefer Java to DRL, maybe the [ConstraintStreams API](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintStreams) could be interesting for you.